# Android backpress not restoring fragments in pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, lifecycle

I navigate from fragment A which has a pager adapter with 2 fragments to fragment B committing the transaction to backstack. On returning to fragment A the pager adapter although initialised fails to load its fragments.

This part runs after returning to fragment A.

```
   @Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    POSPagerAdapter posPagerAdapter = new POSPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(posPagerAdapter);
    setQuantity(cart.quantity);
    setCharge(cart.totalAmount);
    cart.onCartChanged.subscribe(cartChangedSuscriber);
}
```

This is how i'm navigating to fragment B

```
PaymentMethodFragment f = PaymentMethodFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container,f)
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: Code looks ok to me. I think the issue might be related to the adapter or the child fragment implementations.